# Error when checking target: expected dense to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (25000, 1)

Tags: r, keras, deep-learning, lstm

I am trying to execute the following example: https://keras.rstudio.com/articles/examples/imdb_lstm.html

```
library(keras)

max_features <- 20000
batch_size <- 32

# Cut texts after this number of words (among top max_features most common words)
maxlen <- 80  

cat('Loading data...\n')
imdb <- dataset_imdb(num_words = max_features)
x_train <- imdb$train$x
y_train <- imdb$train$y
x_test <- imdb$test$x
y_test <- imdb$test$y

cat(length(x_train), 'train sequences\n')
cat(length(x_test), 'test sequences\n')

cat('Pad sequences (samples x time)\n')
x_train <- pad_sequences(x_train, maxlen = maxlen)
x_test <- pad_sequences(x_test, maxlen = maxlen)
cat('x_train shape:', dim(x_train), '\n')
cat('x_test shape:', dim(x_test), '\n')

cat('Build model...\n')
model <- keras_model_sequential()
model %>%
  layer_embedding(input_dim = max_features, output_dim = 128) %>% 
  layer_lstm(units = 64, dropout = 0.2, recurrent_dropout = 0.2) %>% 
  layer_dense(units = 1, activation = 'sigmoid')

# Try using different optimizers and different optimizer configs
model %>% compile(
  loss = 'binary_crossentropy',
  optimizer = 'adam',
  metrics = c('accuracy')
)

cat('Train...\n')
model %>% fit(
  x_train, y_train,
  batch_size = batch_size,
  epochs = 15,
  validation_data = list(x_test, y_test)
)

scores <- model %>% evaluate(
  x_test, y_test,
  batch_size = batch_size
)

cat('Test score:', scores[[1]])
cat('Test accuracy', scores[[2]])
```

But with one small change to the following line:

```
layer_lstm(units = 64, dropout = 0.2, return_sequences = T, recurrent_dropout = 0.2)
```

I have made `return_sequences= TRUE` as I wish to view the hidden state values at each epoch.

Can you please help me out how to fix the error?

Comment: Please share your complete code and the error message you received.

Comment: No, don't share your complete code but extract a [mcve] from your code. Actually, your question is off-topic without that! Further, make sure you took the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: I have updated the question with a minimal and verifiable example.